# Transforming or simplifying a hypergeometric Function with $z>0$

Tags: summation, hypergeometric-function

How can I simplify, or transform, the following $_2F_1$ expression? Or evaluate its convergence? The $z$ term is problematic.

Expression: $$_2F_1\left(x+y,x;x+1;\dfrac{a+b+d}{b-a}\right)$$
where $x = 1,2,3,\ldots$ and $y = 0,1,2,\ldots$ and $a,b,d>0$ with $a<b$

I've already looked over Abramowitz and Stegun, DLMF (Digital Library of Mathematical Functions), and the Wolfram Functions Database in detail !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

Given $\left(m,n\right)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}\times\mathbb{N}\land\left(a,b,c\right)\in\left(0,\infty\right)^{3}\land a<b$, define

$$f_{m,n}{\left(a,b,c\right)}:={_2F_1}{\left(m+n,n;n+1;\frac{a+b+c}{b-a}\right)},\tag{1}$$

where ${_2F_1}{\left(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z\right)}$ is the [Gauss hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), which is primarily defined via [the infinite series](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/01/)

$${_2F_1}{\left(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z\right)}:=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\alpha\right)_{k}\,\left(\beta\right)_{k}\,z^{k}}{\left(\gamma\right)_{k}\,k!};~~~\small{\left|z\right|<1\lor\left[\left|z\right|=1\land\Re{\left(\gamma-\alpha-\beta\right)}>0\right]}.\tag{2}$$

Note that the argument is $z=\frac{a+b+c}{b-a}$ is greater than unity, provided that $0<a<b\land0<c$:

$$z=\frac{a+b+c}{b-a}=1+\frac{2a+c}{b-a}>1.$$

This prevents us from defining our Gauss hypergeometric function by either its primary infinite series definition or Euler integral definition. Also complicating matters is the integer nature of the parameters.

The [complete definition](http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/02/02/) for the Gauss hypergeometric function includes the following two cases:

$$\begin{align}
{_2F_1}{\left(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z\right)}
&:=\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\beta-\alpha,\gamma-\beta\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-\alpha}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(\beta,\gamma-\beta\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\alpha\right)_{k}\,\left(\alpha-\gamma+1\right)_{k}\,z^{-k}}{\left(\alpha-\beta+1\right)_{k}\,k!}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\beta,\alpha-\beta\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-\beta}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(\beta,\gamma-\beta\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(\beta\right)_{k}\,\left(\beta-\gamma+1\right)_{k}\,z^{-k}}{\left(\beta-\alpha+1\right)_{k}\,k!};~~~\small{\left|z\right|>1\land\alpha-\beta\notin\mathbb{Z}},\tag{3a}\\
\end{align}$$

and

$${_2F_1}{\left(\alpha,\beta;\gamma;z\right)}:=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}{_2F_1}{\left(\alpha,\beta+\epsilon;\gamma;z\right)};~~~\small{\left|z\right|>1\land\alpha-\beta\in\mathbb{Z}}.\tag{3b}$$

---

Letting $\left(m,n\right)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\ge0}\times\mathbb{N}\land z\in\left(1,\infty\right)$,

$$\begin{align}
{_2F_1}{\left(m+n,n;n+1;z\right)}
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}{_2F_1}{\left(m+n,n+\epsilon;n+1;z\right)}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\bigg{[}\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\epsilon-m,1-\epsilon\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-m-n}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(m+n\right)_{k}\,\left(m\right)_{k}\,z^{-k}}{\left(m-\epsilon+1\right)_{k}\,k!}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,m-\epsilon\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-n-\epsilon}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(n+\epsilon\right)_{k}\,\left(\epsilon\right)_{k}\,z^{-k}}{\left(\epsilon-m+1\right)_{k}\,k!}\bigg{]}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\bigg{[}\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\epsilon-m,1-\epsilon\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-m-n}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(m+n,m;m-\epsilon+1;\frac{1}{z}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,m-\epsilon\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-n-\epsilon}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n+\epsilon,\epsilon;\epsilon-m+1;\frac{1}{z}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\bigg{[}\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\epsilon-m,1-\epsilon\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-m-n}\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-m-n}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n+m,1-\epsilon;1-\epsilon+m;\frac{1}{1-z}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,m-\epsilon\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-n-\epsilon}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n+\epsilon,\epsilon;\epsilon-m+1;\frac{1}{z}\right)}\bigg{]}.\\
\end{align}$$

At this point it will be convenient to consider the $m=0$ and $m>0$ cases separately.

Consider first the $m>0$ case, where $\left(m,n\right)\in\mathbb{N}^{2}\land z\in\left(1,\infty\right)$.

$$\begin{align}
{_2F_1}{\left(m+n,n;n+1;z\right)}
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\bigg{[}\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(\epsilon-m,1-\epsilon\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-m-n}\left(1-\frac{1}{z}\right)^{-m-n}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\\
&~~~~~\times\,{_2F_1}{\left(n+m,1-\epsilon;1-\epsilon+m;\frac{1}{1-z}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,m-\epsilon\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-n-\epsilon}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n+\epsilon,\epsilon;\epsilon-m+1;\frac{1}{z}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\bigg{[}\frac{1}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\cdot\frac{\sin{\left(m\pi\right)}\Gamma{\left(1-\epsilon\right)}}{\left(m-\epsilon\right)\sin{\left(\pi\left(\epsilon-m\right)\right)}}\cdot\frac{\Gamma{\left(m\right)}}{\Gamma{\left(m-\epsilon\right)}}\\
&~~~~~\times\left(1-z\right)^{-m-n}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n+m,1-\epsilon;1-\epsilon+m;\frac{1}{1-z}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,m-\epsilon\right)}\,\left(-z\right)^{-n-\epsilon}}{\operatorname{B}{\left(n+\epsilon,1-\epsilon\right)}}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n+\epsilon,\epsilon;\epsilon-m+1;\frac{1}{z}\right)}\bigg{]}\\
&=-\frac{n}{m}\left(1-z\right)^{-m-n}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n+m,1;1+m;\frac{1}{1-z}\right)}\\
&~~~~~+\frac{n\,\operatorname{B}{\left(m,n\right)}}{\left(-z\right)^{n}}\lim_{\epsilon\to0}{_2F_1}{\left(n+\epsilon,\epsilon;\epsilon-m+1;\frac{1}{z}\right)}\\
&=\frac{n\operatorname{B}{\left(m,n\right)}}{\left(-z\right)^{n}}-\frac{n}{m}\left(1-z\right)^{-m-n}\,{_2F_1}{\left(n+m,1;1+m;\frac{1}{1-z}\right)}\\
&=n\left(-z\right)^{-n}\operatorname{B}{\left(m,n\right)}-n\left(-z\right)^{-n}\left(1-z\right)^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\left(1-n\right)_{k}\,\left(-1\right)^{k}}{\left(k+m\right)\,k!\,\left(z-1\right)^{k}}\\
&=n\left(-z\right)^{-n}\operatorname{B}{\left(m,n\right)}-n\left(-z\right)^{-n}\left(1-z\right)^{-m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom{n-1}{k}}{\left(k+m\right)\,\left(z-1\right)^{k}}\\
&=n\left(-z\right)^{-n}\left[\operatorname{B}{\left(m,n\right)}-\left(-1\right)^{m}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{\binom{n-1}{k}}{\left(m+k\right)\,\left(z-1\right)^{m+k}}\right].\\
\end{align}$$

It remains to consider the $m=0$ special case, but for the time being I prefer to leave this as an exercise to the reader...

---

Answer (score 0):

I found Chapter 15 of [Olver, Lozier, Boisvert, Clark (Eds.) (2010). NIST Handbook of Mathematical Functions. New York, NY: Cambridge University Press.] very clear. As far as I know, $\,_{2}F_{1}(a,b,c;z)$ with $a,b,c>0$ converges for $|z|<1$ and diverges otherwise (see page 384).

Comment: This wrong. While it is true that the primary series definition for the hypergeometric function converges for $a,b,c>0\land\left|z\right|<1$ and diverges otherwise, the hypergeometric function itself doesn't necessarily diverge. One merely has to use a modified definition for those conditions.

Comment: @David H I do not ind being proven wrong. David, OP would clearly benefit from more details you seem to have.

Comment: I'm working on a response for OP as as I type this, but it is unfortunately becoming somewhat lengthy. ;)

Comment: @David H I'm just now seeing these comments, I would appreciate a response from you.